# Spring Boot service is not picking up the git.properties file generated by the gi-commit-id maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback, logback-classic, logstash-logback-encoder

I have configured the `git-commit-id` plugin as follows:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
            <includeOnlyProperties>
                <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                <includeOnlyProperty>^git.build.(time|version)$</includeOnlyProperty>
                <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.(abbrev|full)$</includeOnlyProperty>
                <includeOnlyProperty>^git.dirty$</includeOnlyProperty>
            </includeOnlyProperties>
            <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

It works as expected and generates the following `git.properties` file:

```
#Generated by Git-Commit-Id-Plugin
git.build.time=2023-07-13T14\:04\:21+0200
git.build.version=5.0-SNAPSHOT
git.commit.id.abbrev=753455c
git.commit.id.full=753455c7ae51f231cefda280e0508feeb3655f59
git.dirty=true
```

All good!
That file is saved in `target/classes/git.properties`.

I have created the following `PropertySourceConfig.java` file to import the properties from `git.properites`:

```
package com.my.app.metrics;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Generates beans with access to properties required for metrics
 */
@Component
public class PropertySourceConfig {


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propsConfig
                = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propsConfig.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("git.properties"));
        propsConfig.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        propsConfig.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propsConfig;
    }
}
```

This works, I have added fields annotated with `@Value()` pointing at the properties in `git.properties` to one of my controllers, and can see the correct values in those fields when I run the debugger.

I have also added the following `logback-spring.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="applicationName" source="spring.application.name" defaultValue="unknown" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="applicationVersion" source="project.version" defaultValue="unknown" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="commitId" source="git.commit.id.abbrev" defaultValue="unknown" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Here's where my problems start.

`spring.application.name` is picked up as expected.
`project.version` (in `application.properties`) is picked up too.
`git.commit.id.abbrev` (in `git.properties`) is not picked up, and so it shows up as "unknown" in the log output.

What is the issue here?

I want to say the logger is configured before the `PropertySourceConfig` object is created, and so there is no reference to it when the logger starts.

If so, how can I fix that?

Maybe I can't. Perhaps the strategy should be to add is info as a separate metric and push it directly to `CloudWatch` instead of including it in the logs at all?

Comment: The `git.properties` is only used to expose as information in an actuator endpoint. I t isn't loaded as properties, so yes you should tell Spring Boot to load this file if you want to expose it as properties.

Comment: That won't work and might even work against Spring Boot. Ditch that configuration and just write an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that adds the `git.properties` as source to the environment. Or just add an `--spring.config.additional-location` pointing to `classpath:/git.properties` (or where ever it is) to have it loaded. The first is more automatic, the latter requires some work during startup.

Comment: Care to write an answer I can accept?

Comment: Try to add this property in your application.properties file 
spring.config.import=classpath:git.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git.properties` is read only by the info endpoint through the auto configuration. It isn't part of the environment and as such not available for property substitution.

To do this you would need to make sure it is loaded. You can use one of 2 approaches for this.

1. add `spring.config.import=classpath:/git.properties` to your `application.properties`. This should load it next to the `application.properties`.
2. You can write an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to do this.

```java
public class GitInfoAdder implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

  public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    var gitResource = new ClasspathResource("git.properties");
    environment.getPropertySources().addLast(new ResourcePropertySource(gitResource));
  }
}
```

Next you need to add a `spring.factories` to your `src/main/resources/META-INF` directory to load this `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=your.package. GitInfoAdder
```

This will add the properties as well. But I would suggest option 1 that is probably the easiest (and the one I keep forgetting).